# Exam Class: \vsword

Tags: exam

I can already fill in the values of \pointpoints, \vqword, \vpword and
\vtword for \gradetable. How to fill in the \vsword column?

I want to fill it like this.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{exam}
\usepackage[hmargin=1.5cm,bmargin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[indonesian]{babel}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{put}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[inline,shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\let\ds\displaystyle
\parindent0em

\printanswers 
\newcommand{\class}{MATEMATIKA}
\newcommand{\examnum}{\large\bfseries Penskoran Penilaian Tengah Semester Ganjil}
\newcommand{\examdate}{23 September 2019}

\pagestyle{headandfoot}
\firstpageheader{\class}{\examnum}{\examdate}
\runningheader{\class}{\examnum}{Hal. \thepage\ dari \numpages}
\runningfooter{}{}{}
\runningheadrule

\pointpoints{exam-point}{poin}
\pointpoints{bobot}{bobot}
\vqword{No. Soal}
\vpword{Bobot Soal}
\vtword{Jumlah}
\vsword{Skor Maksimum}
\qformat{\bfseries Soal Nomor \thequestion\hspace{14cm} bobot = \totalpoints\hfill}
\renewcommand{\solutiontitle}{\noindent\textbf{Jawaban:}\enspace}

\begin{document}

\rule[2ex]{\textwidth}{1pt}%

\addpoints 
\begin{center}
\gradetable[v][questions]
\end{center}

\begin{questions}
\question[15] 
The question for number one.
    \begin{solution}
The solution
\flushright \textbf{Skor maksimum = 6}
    \end{solution}

 \question[10] 
The question for number two.
\begin{solution}
The solution
\flushright \textbf{Skor maksimum = 3}
   \end{solution}

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please don't post only a snippet, try to make a small complete document that shows the table. You can make it shorter, for example just one question, to make it easier to create the document. This will help anyone who wants to answer with setting up the code and making sure that the answer is actually useful for you.